# copy mysql data from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help, i'm trying to move all of the data from one row/all the clolumns and put it into another table.

So i have a table called ptb_registrations where users information will be sent to and stored, then i want to have this data be copied into ptb_users and then be deleted from ptb_registrations afterwards.

I have an auto_increment on a column called id in my ptb_registrations table so i can use that to identify which row to be copied.

The idea is that after a user registers they recieve an email with a verify link and upon clicking that link somehow the id is echoed (possibly by email WHERE emial = ) and then my code would then go ahead and copy all of id 1's row of data from ptb_registrations and copy into ptb_users for that user.

Here's something i started on, can anyone show me and point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
 <?php
    require_once("session.php"); 
    require_once("functions.php");
    require('_config/connection.php');

    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ptb_users` SELECT * FROM `ptb_registrations`");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a "verified" column in your user table? Set to 0 upon registration and 1 upon verification.

Comment: because then i have thousands of unverified users i have to sort through and delete.

Comment: It's best to keep a record, so if they try to register you tell them they already have and need to verify their account. Also, why do you expect so many users not to verify their accounts?

Answer (score 0):

you are creating more work for you. To check if the user exists/changing password/editing user data.. You will have to constantly reference two tables in your database and end up possibly duplicating your code (code duplication = bad practice) --

and in terms of deleting the unverified users.. You can set a cronjob to run on either a daily,weekly,monthly process to automatically delete the unverified users... Example:

3 Days after registration and still not verified - Email user stating unverified accounts will be deleted

1 week after registration and still not verified - Issue a final warning stating the date their account will be deleted

2 weeks - `DELETE FROM tabl WHERE Verified=0`  issue notification that their account has been removed from your system.

As you provided no in-depth code of what you have tried, I will not include any hints apart from cronjobs.